# HTML image moves to right when it should rotate

Tags: html, css, image

Can someone please tell me why my icon just moves to the right when it's supposed to rotate?

```
.rotate-icon{
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s ease-out;
  -transition: -transform 0.6s ease-out;
} 
.rotate-icon:hover{
  display: inline-block;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
 -transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
img{
 position:absolute;
 top: 95vh;
 left:10%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9zvg0s7/)

Since I am quite new to HTML I can't get it why I doesn't rotate even it should.
My goal is to get a icon on the lower left icon which rotates on hover.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you remove the transform from the image, it does indeed rotate.  Why do you have that transform on the image at all?

Comment: I thought it was necessary to properly place it in the corner.

Well, but thank you very much.

Comment: Your problem, as I write below is connected with transform: translate

Comment: Pro tip: when troubleshooting a problem, _simplify_.  Try various things, make it simpler, then keep adding what you want / need until something breaks - then you know exactly what broke it, and can work on doing that single part differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are applying two transition on single item, which ins't letting rotate work,
remove 
`transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` from img style rule, and it works like you would expect.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75cg79zL/) for you

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you, so that others can take help from it as well, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

It's override this: `-transform: rotate(-360deg);` so you doesn't have good position element.

You should move `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to parent element if you want rotate your element as you write in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `translate()` when you redefine `transform` with `rotate()` on hover. Combine those two `transform` properties and set an initial `rotate()` to transition from.

```css
.rotate-icon{
  display: inline-block;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s ease-out;
 transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
}
.rotate-icon:hover{
  display: inline-block;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-360deg);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-360deg);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-360deg);
}
img{
 position:absolute;
 top: 95vh;
 left:10%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) ;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/2149-200.png" class="rotate-icon">
```

Comment: it doesn't solve a problem with recalculation height/width. You can see it on scrollbar during animation. In my opinion it's not good idea to use translate and rotate for one animation.

Comment: @kris_IV what do you mean "You can see it on scrollbar during animation"? OP positioned the element using `translate()` initially, then is overwriting `translate()` with `rotate()`. I'm assuming they're using `translate()` on purpose to position the element, then they simply want to `rotate()` it at that same position. Why would you remove their original positioning? All they need to do is combine the `transform` properties.

Comment: @michaelcooker look on scrollbar. He put additional css ` top: 95vh;
 left:10%;` and during animation top is not top, left is not left, so you can see that real size of document is changing during animation. For me it doesn't look like good solution. In my opinion he should create parent `div`, position it in good place, and then use only rotate for `img` (child)

Comment: @kris_IV OP's problem is *"tell me why my icon just moves to the right when it's supposed to rotate?"* and *"My goal is to get a icon on the lower left icon which rotates on hover."* - my answer achieves exactly that. You're making assumptions about their original positioning, which isn't part of their problem. They have the image where they want it - they just want it to rotate in that place, which is what my solution does.

Comment: OK- but this problem doesn't exist without your solution.

Comment: @kris_IV "this problem doesn't exist without your solution"* - are you saying *"this problem exists with your solution"*? if so, what problem?

Comment: @kris_IV I don't know how to say it any clearer. OP wants the image to rotate where it is. that is exactly what my solution does.